# Indexing WPF tab controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have bound a tab control to a collection via a ViewModel property. I want the tab headers to reflect the index of the item it is showing, but this seems to be inordinately difficult. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
   <TabControl
            Style ="{StaticResource GtlTabControl}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentImageIndex}">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="???"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
       ...
   </TabControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an AlternationIndex inside the xaml. Something like this:

```
<TabControl Style ="{StaticResource GtlTabControl}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding CurrentImageIndex}"
    AlternationCount="{Binding Path=Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource  FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

There are also alternatives posted here: [Show SelectedIndex in WPF Tabcontrol header template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553238/show-selectedindex-in-wpf-tabcontrol-header-template)

Answer (score 1):

If "`Images`" is a property of type `List<MyImage>`, then you can have an "Id" property in class "MyImage" and use it to bind to "Header"

```
public class MyImage{
  public int Id{get;set;}
}

....<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Yeah this is one solution I came up with, but it's not so elegant. If I add or remove images I need to re-index the collection. Still, it's not as ugly as using a converter!